# Trying to learn and understand the behaviour of unsafe rust within thread execution. Can someone explain what I might done wrong here?

Tags: multithreading, rust, vector, unsafe, raw-pointer

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicPtr, Ordering};
use std::thread;

fn main() {

    let mut arr = vec![1,2,3];
    let ptr = &mut arr as *mut Vec<i32>;
    println!("ptr : {:?}",ptr);
    // unsafe { (*ptr)[0] = 2; }
    let ptr_ref_1 = Arc::new(AtomicPtr::new(ptr));
    let a = thread::spawn(move || unsafe {
        let ptr_inner = (ptr_ref_1).load(Ordering::SeqCst);
        println!("ptr_inner_1 {:?}",ptr_inner);
        (*ptr_inner).push(4);
        println!("4 is done");
    });
    let ptr_ref_2 = Arc::new(AtomicPtr::new(ptr));
    let b = thread::spawn(move || unsafe {
        let ptr_inner = (ptr_ref_2).load(Ordering::SeqCst);
        println!("ptr_inner_2 {:?}",ptr_inner);

        (*ptr_inner).push(5);
        println!("5 is done");
    });
    let ptr_ref_3 = Arc::new(AtomicPtr::new(ptr));
    let c = thread::spawn(move || unsafe {
        // Read value
        // println!("{:?}",*(ptr_ref_3.load(Ordering::SeqCst)));
        let ptr_inner = (ptr_ref_3).load(Ordering::SeqCst);
        println!("ptr_inner_3 {:?}",ptr_inner);

        (*ptr_inner).push(6);
        println!("6 is done");
    });
    a.join().unwrap();
    b.join().unwrap();
    c.join().unwrap();
    println!("final values {:?}",arr);
}
```

95% of the runs work fine , 5% of the runs throw the below error

```
Output : 

ptr : 0x16d65f008
ptr_inner_1 0x16d65f008
ptr_inner_2 0x16d65f008
5 is done
main(75339,0x16d867000) malloc: pointer 0x6000022a8010 being reallocated was not allocated
main(75339,0x16d867000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Signal: SIGABRT (signal SIGABRT)
```

Trying to mutate multiple references to a single pointer of a vector using unsafe rust and threads. I understand how to use Arc/Mutex to update the values in multiple threads but not sure what's the error here with unsafe rust.

Answer (score 6):

This is a simple data race, since you're trying to mutate one `Vec` in three different threads without any synchronization. The fact that you're using `AtomicPtr` is doing nothing here. Usually when you use `AtomicPtr<T>`, it involves swapping it out for another `T` or a null pointer, modifying the original `T`, and then putting it back.

This code is always undefined behavior, but the 5% that actually crashes is probably because the `Vec` reallocates in one thread while another thread is trying to write to it.

This code would probably be best written with a channel.

Comment: Understood. So if use the same code , just for parallel read purposes , this shouldn't  throw any error right , since the vector isn't being modified?

Comment: @NikhilChatragadda The error isn't the problem, the undefined behavior is. Reading is fine, but this code isn't really ideal for any purpose.